# How do args get passed to super when inheriting from a parent class?

Tags: python, super

EDIT: My comment below should be ignored as I still need to work out how to pass arguments here:

A1 = Child('Bird','It Flies','Yes')

Just using get, isn't going to cut it.

Here is a sample of my code, I didn't want to copy and paste everything as it seemed overkill. My issue is this..

Name and Description attributes are set to a string in the Parent class. A1 is part of the Child class.

````
class Parent:
        def __init__(self, Name, Description, arg3):
            self.__Name = "Dog"
            self.__Description = "It walks"
            self.__arg3 = arg3
        
        def getName(self):
            return self.__Name 
            
        def getDescription(self):
            return self.__Description 

        def getArg3(self):
            return self.__arg3
        
        def setName(self, Name):
            self.__Name = Name

        def setDescription(self, Description):
            self.__Description = Description

        def setArg3(self, Code):
            self.__Arg3 = Arg3

            ```
class Child(Parent): 

     def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()'''

A1 = Child('Bird','It flies','Yes')

A1.getName()
A1.getDescription()
A1.getArg3()

OUTPUT:
DOG      #Why is this not overidden by 'BIRD'
IT WALKS #Same for this
Yes      #This one is fine
````

ARG3 is easily overwritten by giving the argument here A1 = Child('Bird','It flies',**'Yes'**). Name and Description continue to get their attributes from the Parent. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Your child class' **init** isn't receiving the arguments you pass it. It should look like

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, Name, Description, arg3):
        super().__init__(Name, Description, arg3)
```

Also, the Parent class sets __Name and __Description no matter what arguments you pass it.

Answer (score 0):

In a classic case of rubber duck debugging, I have resolved this by using a get method that returns Name and Description.

```
        def Name(self):
            return "Name"
```

An explanation of how Super() works would still be welcome though. As sometimes I receive errors like:

```
super().__init__()
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 8 were given
```

I was not aware that you had to pass arguments to init when using super, so it confuses me.